# C#: Finding exact string in excel sheet doesn't work with xlWhole

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

In my excel sheet I'm looking with my program for a key word like "Tescase". The parameter xlWhole dosen't find any range, but xlPart finds the key word. The problem with xlPart ist that it finds all the words in my excel sheet that contains the word "Testcase". But I would like to search only for the exact key word "Testcase".

Hear is my code:

```
var app = new Application();
var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(pExcelFile);
var worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Range range = worksheet.UsedRange; 
            
Range findTestcaseColumn = range.Find(What: "Testcase", LookIn: XlFindLookIn.xlValues, LookAt: XlLookAt.xlWhole);

if (findTestcaseColumn != null ) {
// found
} else {
 //not found
}
```

But xlPart finds the key word "Testcase":

```
Range findTestcaseColumn = range.Find(What: "Testcase", LookIn: XlFindLookIn.xlValues, LookAt: XlLookAt.xlPart);
```

Thanks for suggetions.

Comment: Is the format of the cell with the word "Testcase" in it, text?

Comment: Also, you say "words in my excel sheet that contains the word 'Testcase'", don't you mean *cells* that contains the word Testcase? `xlWhole` should find cells which is an exact match to your search string, which means cells that **only** contain the word "Testcase". Please clarify if what is what you meant.

Comment: Yes, the cell in my excel sheet where "Testcase" is written is text.

Comment: I mean the cells, where the words are written in my excel sheet.

Comment: You wrote: "xlWhole should find cells which is an exact match to your search string, which means cells that only contain the word "Testcase". Please clarify if what is what you meant.", but this is unfortunately not working for me...

Comment: I understand. I asked about the format because I saw a comment elsewhere on the web when searching about someone else asking a similar question, and their problem resolved when they changed the format of the cell to Text. And you clarifying that it was the cells you wanted means that I have no further information. So I guess all I can say right now is good luck, and hope someone else can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here from VBA inside Excel: I fill a cell with a text, then come back later with .find to add something in the cell next to it. With xlPart I find the cell, with xlWhole it fails. Very strange behaviour. Resetting the style of the search column back to standard is a solution, but that's insane of course. It should ignore the style or have an option to do so.

Please join me giving feedback to Microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/office/vba/api/excel.range.find